# Profile picture not displaying properly?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts

(aka: Redacted Stack is too redacted!)

On the main users page, the user Redacted Stack (formerly Major Stackings) has a profile picture which is mainly a solid grey block:

[image: grey block]

But when I hover over his picture, the blowup mini-bio has a real picture:

[image: blowup]

Which also appears on his actual profile page:

[image: profile page]

Is this some sort of bug? I suspect not, since it's happening to him and no other user. Is it possible to 'redact' one's profile picture in this way, or to have two pictures, one for one's actual profile page and one to appear as a thumbnail on the main users page?

Comment: Thanks @Rand al'thor.  I thought I was being punished.

Comment: @RedactedStack That's what happens when you redact yourself too much!

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276920/222298

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like his thumbnail gravatar icon is just messed up.

[image: Thumbnail]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvfsF.jpg?s=48&g=1

However, the small/medium/large alternatives look fine:

[image: Small]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvfsFs.jpg?s=48&g=1

[image: Medium]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvfsFm.jpg?s=48&g=1

[image: Large]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvfsFl.jpg?s=48&g=1

Probably just needs to update the picture again.

Comment: Huh, thanks. So should I report this as a bug? PS: the link you've put below each of the 4 pictures is exactly the same!

Comment: the hyperlinks were right just the text was wrong. fixed. and I'm going to guess it was a glitch in the upload or conversion process on imgur so I'm not sure where to file a big *with*